# Mysql select, How do i find the application names which has values given in the same column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with application name and permissions given to the application. i need to find what are the applications that require both these

```
name   permissions
app1    perm1
app1    perm5
app1    perm6
app2    perm1
app2    perm8
app3    perm1
app3    perm6
app3    perm2
app3    perm4
```

How do i find the application names which has "perm1 and perm6" both....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```
SELECT t.name
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.name
HAVING MAX(IFNULL(t.permissions,'')='perm1')
     + MAX(IFNULL(t.permissions,'')='perm6') = 2
 ORDER BY t.name
```

We're using a GROUP BY and aggregate functions, if we find a row for that has 'perm1', then t.permissons='perm1' returns a 1, otherwise it returns a 0. (We handle the case of a NULL by wrapping t.permissions in an IFNULL function.)

If we find both a 'perm1' and a 'perm6', then the HAVING predicate will evalulate to TRUE, and the row will be returned.

---

Another way to do it, using an EXISTS predicate to run a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.name
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.permissions = 'perm1'
   AND EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1 
           FROM mytable s
          WHERE s.name = t.name
            AND s.permissions = 'perm6'
       )
 GROUP BY t.name
 ORDER BY t.name
```

---

or an equivalent, using an IN predicate:

```
 SELECT t.name
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE t.permissions = 'perm1'
    AND t.name IN 
        ( SELECT s.name
            FROM mytable s
           WHERE s.permissions = 'perm6'
             AND s.name IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY s.name
        )
  GROUP BY t.name
  ORDER BY t.name
```

---

A fourth way to get it would be:

```
 SELECT t.name
   FROM mytable t
   JOIN mytable s
     ON t.name = s.name
    AND t.permissions = 'perm1'
    AND s.permissions = 'perm6'
  GROUP BY t.name
  ORDER BY t.name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name
FROM tableName
WHERE   permissions IN ('perm1','perm6')
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59021/1)

OR

```
SELECT name
FROM tableName
WHERE   permissions IN ('perm1','perm6')
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT permissions) = 2
```

Comment: even this seems to be working... it does give if either of the perm1 or perm6 is percents...

Comment: SELECT `Name`
FROM `Survey_Application`
WHERE `manifest_permission` IN ('android.permission.DUMP','android.permission.INTERNET')
GROUP BY `Name`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 this is how i actually ran it

Comment: This will work if we have a guarantee that there aren't two rows e.g. for name='app1' and permissions='perm1'. If there were, and there weren't any rows with 'perm6', this would return 'app1'.  If there was also a row for 'perm6', then this wouldn't return 'app1', because the COUNT would be 3.

Comment: @spencer7593 this answer hasn't been updated earlier. this will still work if in the `HAVING` clause you will supply `DISTINCT` in the permissiona, eg `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT permissions) = 2`